# runOutsideAngular with drag an drop, service and component

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, zone

I am trying to properly implement `NgZone` `runOutsideAngular` with drag and drop. In my architecture, users can drag an element in a list and drop it at some other position. While dragging, I am showing a marker where the element would be dropped.

[image]

The way I implemented this (for some other reasons) is that while the user drags over an element, I write a reference to it in a service (without explaining all unnecessary details, I am storing the model representing the element in the list that is dragged over (not the dom element)), the component that renders the list will then display a marker at the dragged over element, reading the reference from the service.

Now I am running into performance issues and I have been told to use `runOutsideAngular`. This is how I do it

This is my drag and drop class

```
class MyDragAndDropDirective {

    enableDrag() {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            Observable.fromEvent(this.el, 'dragover').throttleTime(40).subscribe(e => this.onDragOver(<DragEvent> e));
      });
    });

    onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault(); // [1]
        const pos = this.getDragPosition(event);
        this.dndService.setDraggedOverArticle(this.article, pos); // this is where is set the model to the service
    }
}
```

So what I do is I set the handler outside Angular. It seems to me I should run the handler outside angular, however, I still see my UI getting magically updated by angular and my performance does not really get better. It seems it is not really running outside of Angular's digest cycle. I have also tried wrapping the code inside `onDragOver` in `runOutsideAngular`, but it makes no difference.